# Java Multi-Thread Executor InvokeAll Problems

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executor

The code I'm having problems with is:

```
Executor executor = (Executor) callList;

    List<ProgState> newProgList = executor.invokeAll(callList).stream()
            .map(future -> {try {return future.get();} catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}})
            .filter(p -> p!=null).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> The method invokeAll(List>) is undefined for the type Executor

I am told I should use an executor like the one in the code snippet.

The Callables are defined within the following code:

```
List<Callable<ProgState>> callList = (List<Callable<ProgState>>) lst.stream()
            .map(p -> ((Callable<ProgState>)(() -> {return p.oneStep();})))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here is the teacher's code:

```
//prepare the list of callables

 List<Callable<PrgState>> callList = prgList.stream().map(p -> (() -> {return p.oneStep();})).collect(Collectors.toList());

//start the execution of the callables
//it returns the list of new created threads

List<PrgState> newPrgList = executor.invokeAll(callList).stream()
.map(future -> { try {
 return future.get();
 }
 catch(Exception e) {

 //here you can treat the possible
 // exceptions thrown by statements
 // execution

 }
 })
.filter(p -> p!=null).collect(Collectors.toList());


//add the new created threads to the list of existing threads

 prgList.addAll(newPrgList);
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something basic and obvious, but how can you cast a List of Callables to Executor? Wouldn't you instead create your ExecutorService and pass this List into it?

Comment: I'm not so sure myself. I am only a student and I'm trying to understand the teacher's given example.

Comment: Your code looks very wrong to me. What part is the teacher's code, and what part is yours? Do you know how Executors work?

Comment: The code and commentary my teacher wrote on his site:

Comment: //prepare the list of callables
 List<Callable<PrgState>> callList = prgList.stream()
 .map(p -> (() -> {return p.oneStep();}))
 .collect(Collectors.toList())

 //start the execution of the callables
 //it returns the list of new created threads
 List<PrgState> newPrgList =
 executor.invokeAll(callList). stream()
 . map(future -> { try {
 return future.get();
 }
 catch(Exception e) {
 //here you can treat the possible
 // exceptions thrown by statements
 // execution
 }
 })
 .filter(p -> p!=null)
 . collect(Collectors.toList())

Comment: //add the new created threads to the list of existing threads
 prgList.addAll(newPrgList);

Comment: Please post this as an edit to your question and not in comments since we can't read this in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast list of Callables with ExecutorService. You need to define ExecutorService which will inturn pick up callables and execute them in one or multiple threads in parallel.

This is what i think you are after:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();//change executor type as per your need.
List<ProgState> newProgList = executor.invokeAll(callList).stream().map(future -> {...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use stream(), why not parallelStream() as it would be much simpler.

```
 List<PrgState> prgStates = prgList.parallelStream()
                                   .map(p -> p.oneStep())
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This way you have no thread pool to configure, start or stop when finished.

Some might suggest that `parallelStream()` was the main reason for adding Stream and lambdas to Java 8 in the first place. ;)